# Problems with Android and MySQL/PHP database connection

Tags: android, mysql, connection, httpurlconnection

I'm making a very simple Android app, but when I try to connect it to a web page it doesn't work. I have already tried a lot of tutorials on internet and I have already read a lot of topics here too, but without any success.
So now I will explain you my code, hoping we can find a solution together. Thank you for now.

This is the main java page, where I make the connection on the OnClick method:

```
package com.example.enchan.crazyup;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.net.URL;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FollowUsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_follow_us);

        findViewById(R.id.subscribe).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
                String pkg = getPackageName();


                URL url_page = null;

                try {
                    url_page = new URL("http://crazyup.altervista.org/select_email.php?email==" + email.getText().toString());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) url_page.openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                Intent OpenNewEmailActivity = new Intent(FollowUsActivity.this, NewEmailActivity.class);
                Intent intent = OpenNewEmailActivity.putExtra(pkg + "Test", email.getText().toString());
                startActivity(OpenNewEmailActivity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the corrispondent .xml main file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_follow_us"
    tools:context="com.example.enchan.crazyup.FollowUsActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subscribe"
        android:src="@drawable/iscriviti"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_above="@+id/subscribe"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Indirizzo Email"
        android:id="@+id/email_title"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the Manifest there are these permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The php page is this (and it works if I open it on browser):

```
    <?php

mysql_connect("localhost","crazyup","");
mysql_select_db("my_crazyup");

$s_email = $_GET['email'];
$string = "INSERT INTO email (content) VALUES ('".$s_email."')";
$q = mysql_query($string);

if (!$q) {
    die("Errore nella query: " . mysql_error());
}

/* $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE email =".$s_email);
while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[] = $e;
print(json_encode($output)); */

mysql_close();

?>
```

I have read that a probably problem could be the Android version (Marshmallow or Lollipop) but I've tried both and I have the same thing.
In the logcat there are NO errors, so I can't understand why the app not works.

Comment: I see from your Java code that you are not using the client object: is there a reason? Also, specify "doesn't work": does it block somewhere?

Comment: I don't use the client object because other solution tha I've found don't work. When I say that the app doesn't work I mean that nothing happen. There are no errors but any reaction too. How can I change my code to try to work it ? Thank you. Ps. sorry for my bad english, I'm italian.

Comment: is NewEmailActivity an Activity created by you? your objective is to make user send an email if he click the button?

Comment: Yes, I've created the NewEMailActivity, because after the web page call, I need to go to another activity (and it works correctly)

Comment: I need to check if the email that the user insert is present in the db and after that make a newsletter

Comment: The problem is that you do not do any call to your server, because at the click you only go to the email activity

Comment: Is the code correct for you ?

Comment: No, it is not correct

Comment: It's the call, isn't it ?

`code`
try {
     url_page = new URL("http://crazyup.altervista.org/select_email.php?email==" + email.getText().toString());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) url_page.openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`code`

Comment: What I need to do over the HttpURLConnection to call the web page by GET method ?

Comment: I wrote an answer that should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `onClick` method, we will user [Google Volley framework](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url_page = "http://crazyup.altervista.org/select_email.php?email==" + email.getText().toString();

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_page,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        Log.i("stringRequest", response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("stringRequest", "FAILED" + error.getMessage());
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

**OLD ANSWER**, using some deprecated classes

```
// Create http client object to send GET request to server
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Create URL string
String url_page = "http://crazyup.altervista.org/select_email.php?email==" + email.getText().toString();

try
{
     String response = "";
     // Create Request to server and get response
     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url_page);
     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

     // Execute request
     response = Client.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);

     // Log request's response
     Log.i("httpGet", response);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     Log.e("httpGet", "FAILED" + ex.getMessage());
     ex.printStackTrace();
}

//starts new Activity
Intent OpenNewEmailActivity = new Intent(FollowUsActivity.this, NewEmailActivity.class);
Intent intent = OpenNewEmailActivity.putExtra(pkg + "Test", email.getText().toString());
startActivity(OpenNewEmailActivity);
```

disclaimer: I used the code at [this link](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_Get_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=63) for the get request code

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I insert your code Android Studio tell me that it can't resolve HttpGet but I can import anything with Alt + Enter. Is this class deprecate ? Because it's one of my problems when I try to use other examples that I have found on web.

Comment: of course they are available, import everything with Alt+Enter

Comment: It say that I can make a new class with Alt + Enter in this case but without import anything. In other cases, for example Button or View etc. I can import. I have read that HttpGet is deprecate, it's right ?

Comment: @ReiAyanami, I added a new answer, please try it :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have the same problem. I've found a solution only for the Volley class

Comment: @ReiAyanami, does the solution with Volley class work?

Comment: No because I have the same error about Android can't resolve Stringrequest class